# UWP InkCanvas borracha média

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp

Estou fazendo uma aplicação UWP onde tenho o InkCanvas, e implementei a borracha para apagar os desenhos que fiz, mas o modo Erasing é como se fosse a borracha de traços do OneNote, no entanto o que eu preciso seria a Borracha Média do OneNote também, que apenas apagaria onde ela passasse por cima.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você resolveu usando o "InkCanvasEditingMode.EraseByPoint" ?

Comment: Certo, e qual a duvida? Seria bom por seu código e dizer o que tentou e o que não deu certo, além de dizer só a intenção. Aqui tem umas dicas: [ask]